# NGINX setup for history pushState for multiple apps / locations

Tags: nginx, url-routing, pushstate, html5-history

At this point, for one subdomain, I can deploy an uglified `react-router-redux` basic example and have it work with the history API (pushState).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/iot/public_html/xtest;
    server_name iot.sitebuilt.net;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

you can see this at http://iot.sitebuilt.net

I would like to use that subdomain for more than one SPA. So I tried adding a other location (with a similar app for now)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/iot/public_html/xtest;
    server_name iot.sitebuilt.net;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ^~ /basic {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /basic/index.html;
    }
}
```

So I created a /home/iot/public_html/xtest/basic and put a similar app there. It finds the right index.html but does nothing but display the heading. http://iot.sitebuilt.net/basic

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>react-router-redux basic example</title>
    <meta charset="utf8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h4>in xtest/basic</h4>
    <div id="mount"></div>
    <script src="./vendors.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How would I be aple to have multiple apps with pushstate routing running off one NGINX subdomain?

(I have tried to use the idesas of "How to setup NGINX to deploy different Single Page Apps (SPA's… i.e static files) depending on location (under same server_name) with subroutes" without success)